# numpy `arange` exceeds end value

Tags: python, numpy, range, precision

I had expected numpy's `arange(start, end)` to produce values in the range [start, end].  The following example demonstrates that that's not always true (the final value is larger than `end`):

```
import numpy as np

start = 2e9
end = start + 321
step = 0.066833171999
x = np.arange(start, end, step=step)
print x[-1] > end  # Prints "True"
print x[-1] - end  # Prints 0.00013661384582519531
```

The error seems far too large to be caused by machine precision (but perhaps I'm thinking about it incorrectly).  What's going on?

I'm using Numpy version 1.10.1.

Comment: What `dtype` is being used for `x`?

Comment: @Blckknght x.dtype is dtype('float64')

Comment: @hpaulj  `x.shape[0]*step = 321.066558283196`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `arange` docs:

> Array of evenly spaced values.
>
> For floating point arguments, the length of the result is `ceil((stop - start)/step)`. Because of floating point overflow, this rule may result in the last element of out being greater than stop.

Your `step` times the length of the array is larger than 321.  `linspace` is more careful about end points.